# I need to pass the value of the variable from javascript to php how can I do it?

Tags: javascript, php

This is the code and this is a variable price value `parseFloat(preco).toFixed(4);` that's refreshed every 2 seconds. I need to pass this to a PHP variable, how can I do it? I have tried various ways but it does not work for me. It must be something so simple and I'm overlooking it.

```
var preco;
var valor;

var HttpClient = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }

        anHttpRequest.open( "POST", aUrl, true );            
        anHttpRequest.send( null );
    }
}
var HttpClient2 = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }

        anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
        anHttpRequest.send( null );
    }
}

var HttpClient3 = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }

        anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
        anHttpRequest.send( null );
    }
}

var client = new HttpClient();
var client2 = new HttpClient2();
var client3 = new HttpClient3();

let paragrafo = document.createElement("p");
paragrafo.setAttribute("id", 'dracoVlr');

let total = document.createElement("p");
total.setAttribute("id", 'dracodolares');

let totalr = document.createElement("p");
totalr.setAttribute("id", 'dracoreais');

let totale = document.createElement("p");
totale.setAttribute("id", 'dracoeuro');

let inputvlr = document.createElement("input");
inputvlr.setAttribute("id", 'dracoInput');
inputvlr.setAttribute("type", "number")
inputvlr.setAttribute("placeholder", "Cantidad de DRACOS")
inputvlr.setAttribute("value", localStorage.getItem('dracoVlr1'))
let texto = document.createTextNode("Precio DRACO" + ' - ' + parseFloat(preco).toFixed(4));
paragrafo.appendChild(texto);
let body = document.body;

body.appendChild(paragrafo);
body.appendChild(inputvlr);
body.appendChild(total);
body.appendChild(totalr);
body.appendChild(totale);

function display() {

client.get('https://api.mir4global.com/wallet/prices/draco/daily', function(response) {
var retorno = JSON.parse(response);
preco = retorno.Data[retorno.Data.length - 1].USDDracoRate
var input = document.querySelector('input');
valor = input.value;
localStorage.setItem('dracoVlr1', input.value);
document.title = 'Draco' + ' - $' + parseFloat(preco).toFixed(4);
document.getElementById('dracoVlr').innerHTML = "Preço do Draco" + ' - $' + parseFloat(preco).toFixed(4);

});

client2.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BUSDBRL', function(response) {
    
    var binance = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(binance.price)
    document.getElementById('dracodolares').innerHTML = 'Total em Dólares: $' + (valor * preco).toFixed(4)
    document.getElementById('dracoreais').innerHTML = 'Total em Reais: R$' + ((valor * preco)*binance.price).toFixed(4)

});

client3.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=EURBUSD', function(response) {
    
    var binance3 = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(binance3.price)
    document.getElementById('dracodolares').innerHTML = 'Total em Dólares: $' + (valor * preco).toFixed(4)
    document.getElementById('dracoeuro').innerHTML = 'Total en Euros: EUR' + ((valor * preco)*binance3.price).toFixed(4)
});

}

var results= parseFloat(preco).toFixed(4);
<?php $results = "<script>document.write(results)</script>"?>  

const createClock = setInterval(display, 2000);
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Comment: Add the data here instead of null: `anHttpRequest.send( null );`.

Comment: You make a request to the server and pass the value to PHP as data. Maybe that's what you were overlooking, that AJAX requests can contain data?

Comment: There I edited the code, I was missing what I had done to show the variable in php but it does not work for me. This is what I put, but it does not take the value in any part of the code.
`var results= parseFloat(preco).toFixed(4);
<?php $results = "<script>document.write(results)</script>"?>  

const createClock = setInterval(display, 2000);
</script> 

<?php echo $results;?>`

Answer (score 1):

Ajax example for it  in your PHP file request   `$result = $_POST['variable'];`

```
let texto = document.createTextNode("Precio DRACO" + ' - ' + parseFloat(preco).toFixed(4));
    
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'yourphpfile.php',
       data: {
          'variable': texto
       },
    });                                                                                                                               
                 
    
    $result = $_POST['variable'];
```

Comment: in this example, https://jsfiddle.net/newhck/4r1L2kvh/5/  in which line do I add it?

i add this to libraries
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxy/1.6.1/scripts/jquery.ajaxy.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxy/1.6.1/scripts/jquery.ajaxy.js" ></script>`
sorry all question im learning this

Comment: there is no way to make it work i try with this tutorial (https://cdynamicprogramming.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_96.html) and nothing, i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get the value asynchronously and try to use it before it's computed. Let me explain what seems to happen:

1. The two seconds passed
2. A request is sent to client1
3. A request is sent to client2
4. A request is sent to client3
5. clienti responds and its callback is executed
6. clientj responds and its callback is executed
7. clientk responds and its callback is executed

We know that i <> j <> k <> i. The problem is that you do not guarantee that i is 1. Yet, you intend to use the results of the callback of your request to client1 in the callbacks of the requests sent to client2 and client3.

You will need to have something like this:

```
function display() {
    client.get('someurl', function(response) {
        //compute your values
        client2.get('someurl2', function(response2) {/* ... */});
        client3.get('someurl2', function(response3) {/* ... */});
    });
}
```

This way you guarantee that the requests to `client2` and `client3` are only sent once you have got a response to your request to `client` and you have computed your variable.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple example of how can pass Javascript variables to PHP you can understand how to pass variables to PHP. According to your script `let texto = document.createTextNode("Precio DRACO" + ' - ' + parseFloat(preco).toFixed(4));` this is the Javascript variable and as example i pass this to like `<?php echo "<script>window.alert(texto)</script>"; ?>`

Comment: but I need it in a php variable (example: $result) just not in a windows alert

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/newhck/4r1L2kvh/2/

Here is working i need to pass the DRACO Price "the numbers" to a php variable like $result

Comment: Need to use AJAX for it like this

Javascript code
let texto = document.createTextNode("Precio DRACO" + ' - ' + parseFloat(preco).toFixed(4));

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'yourphpfile.php',
   data: {
      'variable': texto
   },
});                                                                                                                               
             
In your php file
$result = $_POST['variable'];

Comment: It does not work for me or I am putting it wrong, create the file php result.php and add the code that you told me but the rest of the code does not work for me, could you send me a where to put it, please, I would be very grateful

Comment: I put a another answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i cant make it work :(